# Ajax/Json post to aspx page results in 404 error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to do an ajax post to c#.  When I do the post though, it results in a 404 error.  Here's my code: 
Javascript:

```
var submitParams = {
                            'companyName': $("#company_name").val(),
                            'companyAddress1': $("#company_address_1").val()
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ClientManagement.aspx/Submit",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            async: true,
                            data: JSON.stringify({ submitParams }),
                            success: function () {
                                alert("hi");
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                debugger;
                            }
                        });

c# code:
    [WebMethod]
    public static void Submit(object parameters)
    {
        string name = parameters.ToString();
    }
```

So it can't find my ClientManagement.aspx/Submit method.  It jumps straight into my "error" function.  Also, this is being performed on a regular aspx page.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the file path? That should get you where you want to go. Is ClientManagement.aspx in the same directory as the file making the AJAX call?

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see where/if an exception occurs?  Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  There are quiet a few things missing that would help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as

```
url: "/ClientManagement.aspx/Submit"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, ASP.NET Web Services have a .asmx file extension. If that does not work, try using the fully qualified domain name of the web service.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of trying to resolve this, I came to the head shaking realization that I misspelled my page name.  In my ajax post, I'm calling ClientManagement.aspx.  My real page was misspelled as ClientManagment.aspx (missing the 'e').

Thanks for your help.